# Weighted average score

Tags: statistics

There are 2 exams of 100 marks each having weightage of 30%each and three quizzes of 30 marks each and weightage for the whole quiz is 40%.But here quizzes are of 30 marks not 100, different subject have different maximum marks.see the picture for more info!

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CsPb.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CsPb.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPpOd.jpg)
Where is the 4 marks going????

Comment: (examScore/100)*0.3 + (examScore/100)*0.3 + (totalQuiz/90)*0.4 = 1 = 100% (not 100 marks)

Answer (score 1):

All points (marks) are not of equal value in this scoring system.

Each exam point is worth $\frac{1}{100}$ of $\frac{30}{100}$ of the entire grade. That's $\frac{3}{1000}$ of the grade.

Similarly, each quiz point is worth $\frac{1}{90}$ of $\frac{40}{100}$ of the entire grade. That's $\frac{4}{900}$ of the entire grade.

The work you set up treats the points as if they all had equal value in the entire grade.

A student's weighted average would be calculated as
$$T\cdot\frac{3}{1000} + Q\cdot\frac{4}{900}$$ where $T$ is the total (sum) of the scores on the two tests; and $Q$ is the total of all the quizzes.

Then for a perfect score ($T=200, Q=90$), we get an overall grade of $1$ (or $100\%$).